# What are use cases of Esri CityEngine?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, 3d, software-recommendations, cityengine

I would like to know the use cases of [Esri CityEngine](http://www.esri.com/software/cityengine), and what distinguish this tool from the other standard GIS like ArcMap and QGIS? and in which fields could be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some [case studies](http://www.esri.com/software/cityengine/resources/casestudies) for CityEngine. On the [main CityEngine website](http://www.esri.com/software/cityengine) it goes into detail about how it can be used and [what features are supported](http://www.esri.com/software/cityengine/features) that might give it an advantage over the tools you specify in your question.

Comment: First link (to case studies) is broken.